# Is it possible to share a filtered board?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am wondering if it is possible to filter a kanban board and then share that filtered view of the board via url? For example, if I filtered the board to only show the currentIteration, is there a url I can use to share that with other team members? I know you can do that with the Sprint Taskboard, but am hoping to be able to do the same with the kanban board in order to show the story progression visually to different stakeholders.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this feature is currently not supported in Azure DevOps.

You cannot share boards url with filters to other users.

I can fully understand your requirements.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]